# Moving a DriveItem changes its id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive, sharepoint-api

On some sharepoint sites, moving a file using the [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) changes the itemid after it is moved...

This used to never change file id before, now it does and as a result breaks a lot of our app code.

Comment: Are you moving with a doc lib, between doc libs in the same site, or between doc libs in different sites? Any idea when you noticed a change in behavior?

Comment: I'm moving files in the same doc lib in the same site (/sites/root/drive/root basically). This started happening during June.

Also noticed another bug in the same move API, it doesn't return the new item anymore after the file is moved (this one started happening Jun 22, 2020 8:42:44 AM UTC )

Comment: Another issue I noticed, when I send a batch to move multiple file, it doesn't return 200 status anymore but 202 now..

Comment: I've escalated this change in behavior to the appropriate team

Comment: Do you happen to pass the `respond-async` preference when you trigger a move?

Comment: @Brad not at all. Didn't even know that header existed up until now. The behavior last happened Jun 26, 2020 2:59:59 PM UTC, and can't reproduce today. It seems fixed somehow, maybe related to the id bug, can't tell.

Comment: Pretend that header doesn't exist for now, otherwise you may opt in to the behavior you don't want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a recent change that resulted in a move within a doclib generating a new ID. This change was disabled and so you should now see the old behavior.

Comment: I have check just checked, this seems fixed, thank you.

Comment: I'm getting this behavior now with Microsoft Graph v5 :(