# Microsoft graph: Moving OneDrive file to a different folder in the same drive gets a different file Id after move operation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are using the below graph endpoint to move a drive item within the same drive.

```
PATCH /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
```

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the expected response is `200 OK` with representation of the newly moved item.

But since 24 June, it is returning status Code: `202 Accepted` with empty response.

After the move, doing a get call on the same item id is returning `404`. It turns out that the moved file has gotten a new Id and that was not the case earlier.

It is happening only for files but not for folders.

```
client-request-id: d1d6b2e4-7d85-4f8d-804b-a100f8d97381
request-id: 82e9a06d-a0ac-42d4-aa4b-be050f7ad87f
```

This is a breaking change and impacting hundreds of customers.

Comment: While my answer should provide enough detail, I'm curious to know if your requests to move happen to include a `Prefer: respond-async` header?

Comment: No, we did not include Prefer:respond-async header.

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming! And it looks like my answer was deleted because it was the same as I gave for a similar question. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538140/moving-a-driveitem-changes-its-id

Comment: I just checked it. It seems to be working fine now, thank you @Brad